# Security considerations when using Google Play App Signing

Tags: android, google-play, android-keystore

I just enrolled to [App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) in Play console and everything works great.

But how should I treat my new upload keystore and its passwords now?
Can I just put this keystore under version control and put passwords into build script in plain text?

As I understand this keystore is only used to temporary sign my apk prior to upload. So I consider it to be pretty safe, since nobody except myself can actually upload new apk to Play, and there is no option to access my original release keystore by knowing upload keys.

Another thing that bothers me now is that I can't see any option to change upload keystore. Is it possible now, or at least planned to be added to Play console soon? If I'll publish my upload keystore and passwords to version control it would be nice to have an option to switch to a new private keystore, if something will go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question (based on [Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/6cohlc/what_is_the_benefit_of_google_play_app_signing/)).

In order to change upload keystore you will need to [contact](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs) Google support and request a reset. It is not the easiest option, but still good to have one.

Can't see big issues to keep upload certificate along with its password in a private repository. As long as it is not possible to automatically push production builds it sounds safe enough and also simplifies Alpha / Beta builds distribution.

Some people have reasonable concerns that by sharing release keystore with Google it may be compromised or used by Google to integrate malicious code into your app. But chances of it are pretty small so as long as you are not working on Facebook or other very popular apps it should be safe enough to rely on Google.

Answer (score 1):

The way you handle your keystore is pretty personal, but publishing it into your source control specially with the password is not a good idea.

You are right when you say that only you can upload the apk into your account, but your account can be compromized for various reasons, so it is always good to have a second step to upload any apk for your account.

When I worked into a team, since  we had a private source control we upload the keystore with our codebase. But the password was managed through 1password.

Now that I work alone, I handle myself my keystore.

About your question to changing the keystore. This is not possible. That are two things you can't change after you uploaded your apk: the package and the keystore. This is done for security reasons.

You can have more info here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html

Comment: I know that it is not possible to change or even delete release keystore, which makes perfect sense to me. But why can't I change upload keystore?

Comment: Actually Google specifically mentioned that you can reset upload keystore in their IO talk [here](https://youtu.be/L9uKkhCCRZA?t=1221)

Comment: Speaking of account compromising, when starting using App Signing Google asks you to enable 2-steps verification, which ideally should prevent from such situation. Compromising account used for app publishing can lead to other sad consequences, among them ability to upload new apk is not most terrible I guess, so you better keep it secure anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As @jonathanrz said, it's best to keep your keystore files private.
It's super easy to use a `gradle.properties` file to store you keystore passwords, and then just reference property values in your `build.gradle` file.

Just remember to guard the keystore files with your life, keep backups of them in multiple places, if you lose them, you'll have to re-upload your app.

Comment: Keeping important passwords in plain text on your machine is not the most secure option I think. And a good thing about new App Signing feature is that you should now be free from a fear of loosing your keystore or passwords.

Comment: I think that was the point of the question. Sure enough if you can keep something locally and ensure it is safe, backed up, etc - it is better not to upload things to the cloud. If you are sure that you won't forget your password it is better not to write it down. But yet - all those unfortunate things happen. And if they do - you can loose ability to update your own app in Google Play. What bad thing can happen if you submit this information to git? How likely it will be compromised?